# Installing OpenJDK 11 on Linux(Azure) using yum or wget

Tags: java, linux, azure-devops, java-11, yum

I want to install & configure openjdk 11 on Linux(vm in azure devops) either by yum or wget , i am new, not sure i tried using wget but openjdk 11 is not downloading

Need OpenJDK 11 to run Sonarqube

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 0):

According to this post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1466580/unable-to-download-oracle-jdk-8-using-wget-command

"Following a licensing change of Oracle Java on 16 April 2019, Oracle now forbids anyone from downloading Java outside of their approved process.

That process is currently to log in to an Oracle account, accept the new license, then attempt the download with the authentication cookies in place."

In order to download it now you must use apt-get command if you use ubuntu or debian so on.
I know it says java 8 but this applies to all java versions

EDIT: I do not use centos so I cannot personally test this but try if this works
$ sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel

or

$ sudo yum install java-11-openjdk

Answer (score 0):

You can try below scripts to install jdk 11 on azure linux vm.

```
sudo rpm --import http://repos.azul.com/azul-repo.key
sudo curl http://repos.azul.com/azure-only/zulu-azure.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/zulu-azure.repo
sudo yum -q -y update
sudo yum -q -y install zulu-11-azure-jdk
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/fundamentals/java-jdk-install#download-and-install-the-azul-zulu-for-azure---enterprise-edition-jdks-from-a-yum-repository) for more information.